# C++: Outputing Multidimensional Arrays on loop?

Tags: c++

Hi everybody I have being trying to do this the whole morning but I can't seem to make it work and is to output a multidimensional array on a loop, let me explain better with a non multidimensional one:

```
int j;
int line[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4,};


  for(j = 0; j < 4; j ++)
  {

      cout << line[j] << endl;

  }
```

This works but when for multidimensional arrays comes its headache:

```
int i, j;
int line[2][2];

line[0][0] = 99;
line[0][1] = 98;
line[1][0] = 97;
line[1][1] = 96;

i = 0;
j = 0;

for(j; j <= 1; j ++)
{
    for(i; i <= j; i ++)
    {
        cout << line[i][j] << endl;
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << line[j][i] << endl;
    }
}
```

What is going on:

So when you enter the loop `j = 0`. You enter the inner loop `i` will start at `0` and go to `1` but `j` will stay that same as `0`, then once `i = 2` (because 2 is not < 2 it will exit the inner loop and continue on with the 1st loop and `j` will now equal `1`, it will re-enter the inner loop and `i` will start again at `0` and increment to `1`. Then once `j = 2` (once again, because 2 is not < 2) it will exit the first loop.

Keeping track you get in this order:

```
[0][0]
[0][1]
[1][0]
[1][1]
```

Why this code:

```
for(j; j <= 1; j ++)
{
    for(i; i <= j; i ++)
    {
        cout << line[i][j] << endl;
    }
}
```

won't work.

So you enter the 1st loop, `j = 0`. You enter the second loop, `i = 0`. It runs through the inner loop once, and you print `line[0][0]`, then `i = 1` second time, is `1 <= 0`? No. So it exits the inner loop and goes to the first loop. `j=1` now. Go into the second loop, you didn't re-initialize `i` to `0` so `i` still equals `1`. Now you have printed `line[1][1]`, Increment `i` and you get `i = 2`. Is 2 <= 1? No. Abort the inner loop. `j` equals `2` is `2 <= 1` no abort loop. You managed to print:

```
[0][0]
[1][1]
```

Comment: Thanks but it still not output the other part of the array

Comment: @LeandroTheBest Either you haven't provided your real code, or you haven't accurately pasted anon's code, or you're lying :)

Comment: LOL sorry I dont ussualy copy and paste stuff :P i wrote 1 instead of 2 silly of me, jeje now this works...

But why is this?

Comment: @anon, o thaks bro, I really did a big miss there, thank for explanation.

Comment: Now I can make one with 3 dimensions

Answer (score 1):

To nicely print a 2D array of size `n x m`, use

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
    {
        cout << a[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hi I don't seem to get it, the values of n m are the same as x or they 3 are same values

Comment: @LeandroTheBest In your example you have a matrix of size 2x2 so, n is 2 an m is 2, for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

correction in inner loop condition ! and exchanging of index variables

```
for(j=0; j <= 1; j ++)
{
    for(i=0; i <= 1; i ++)
    {
        cout << line[j][i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Edited code ^^

Comment: @LeandroTheBest : yeah, missed the `for(i=0` in the inner loop ... works now.

Comment: This does same as anon's code is slighty diferent but also works 
but why it cannot be i <= j; hmmm